# display twitter updtaes in my web site

Tags: php, twitter

I am developing a php web site. Here I want to display twitter updates in my web site. I have a twitter account. But I don't know how I will display the twitter updates. Does anyone know?
Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/get-latest-twitter-status/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help. http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I have done it for a wordpress long time ago, but I guess, that if you want some personal solution ( in a matter of speaking ) you could use that. But better to look at the examples they provide https://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_list or https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api

```
/**
 * Function for displaying twitter statuses
 *
 * @param string $userName
 * @param int $howMany
 */
function display_tweets( $userName, $howMany = 3 )
{
    $statuses = json_decode( file_get_contents( "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name={$userName}&count={$howMany}" ) );

    echo '<div style="width: 300px;"><ol style="list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;">';

    foreach ( $statuses as $Status )
    {
        $statusText = $Status->text;

        if ( ! empty( $Status->entities->urls ) )
        {
            foreach ( $Status->entities->urls as $Url )
            {
                if ( '' !== trim( $Url->expanded_url ) )
                {
                    $statusText = str_replace( $Url->url, "<a href=\"{$Url->expanded_url}\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\">{$Url->display_url}</a>", $statusText );
                }
            }
        }

        $from = '';

        if ( null !== $Status->place )
        {
            $from = $Status->place->full_name;
        }

        display_tweet( $statusText, $userName, $Status->id, $Status->created_at, $from );
    }

    echo '</ol></div>';
}

/**
 * Function for displaying status in url ( user-readable-language :) )
 * 
 * @param string $statusText
 * @param string $userName
 * @param int $statusId
 * @param string $createdAt
 * @param string $from
 */
function display_tweet( $statusText, $userName, $statusId, $createdAt, $from = '' )
{
    echo '<li style="border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC; padding: 5px 0px; overflow: hidden;">';
    echo '<span class="status-body">';
        echo '<span class="status-content">';
            echo '<span class="entry-content">';
            echo $statusText;
            echo '</span>';
        echo '</span>';

        echo '<span class="meta entry-meta" style="display: block; color: #999; font-size: x-small;">';
            echo "<a class=\"entry-date\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://twitter.com/{$userName}/status/{$statusId}\">";
            echo '<span class="published timestamp">' . date( 'g:i A M jS, Y', strtotime( $createdAt ) ) . '</span>';
            echo "</a>";

            if ( '' !== trim( $from ) )
            {
                echo ' from ';
                echo "<a class=\"geocoded_google_link\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://maps.google.com/maps?q={$from}\">{$from}</a>";
            }

        echo '</span>';
    echo '</span>';
    echo '</li>';
}
```